AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'hostname'
I am receiving the below error if I use set_fact and {% if %} {% else %} statements in my playbook.
FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'hostname'. 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'hostname'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/runner/project/playbooks/Stack_Status.yml': line 148, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Write report data\n      ^ here\n"}

The piece of code having issue is here:
- name: Set final stack version fact
      set_fact:
        stack_version: >
          {% if composer_stack is defined and composer_stack != 'Stack not deployed' %}
            {{ composer_stack }}
          {% elif fleet_agent_stack is defined and fleet_agent_stack != 'Stack not deployed' %}
            {{ fleet_agent_stack }}
          {% else %}
            V3 Stack not deployed
          {% endif %}

- name: Gather server report
      set_fact:
        server_report: >
          {
            "hostname": "{{ inventory_hostname }}",
            "stack_version": "{{ stack_version | default('N/A') }}"
          }

- name: Write report data
      shell: |
        echo "\"{{ server_report.hostname }}\",\"{{ server_report.stack_version }}\"" >> "{{ report_file }}"

I am expecting to either display the version of Composer if it is running, or print the version of Fleet-Manager and both are not running display, Stack is not deployed.

The error message says it already
AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'hostname'

the string object is not a dictionary since with the given set_fact: server_report task only a string with YAML content was created.
The minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: example
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - set_fact:
      stack_version: >
        {% if composer_stack is defined and composer_stack != 'Stack not deployed' %}
        {{ composer_stack }}
        {% elif fleet_agent_stack is defined and fleet_agent_stack != 'Stack not deployed' %}
        {{ fleet_agent_stack }}
        {% else %}
        V3 Stack not deployed
        {% endif %}

  - set_fact:
      server_report: >
        {
           "hostname": "{{ inventory_hostname }}",
           "stack_version": "{{ stack_version | default('N/A') }}"
        }

  - name: Content of variable is
    debug:
      var: server_report | type_debug

  - name: Whereby it should be
    debug:
      var: server_report | from_yaml | type_debug

  - name: Now it is working
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ( server_report | from_yaml ).hostname | trim }}"

  - name: Even for
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ( server_report | from_yaml ).stack_version | trim }}"

will result into an output of
PLAY [example] *******************************

TASK [set_fact] ******************************
ok: [host.example.com]

TASK [set_fact] ******************************
ok: [host.example.com]

TASK [Content of variable is] ****************
ok: [host.example.com] =>
  server_report | type_debug: str

TASK [Whereby it should be] ******************
ok: [host.example.com] =>
  server_report | from_yaml | type_debug: dict

TASK [Now it is working] *********************
  msg: host.example.com

TASK [Even for] ******************************
ok: [host.example.com] =>
  msg: V3 Stack not deployed

Documentation Links

from_yaml filter – Convert YAML string into variable structure
to_yaml filter – Convert variable to YAML string
from_json filter – Convert JSON string into variable structure
to_json filter – Convert variable to JSON string
When to use from_json filter in Ansible?

